# `ffprobe` is 12 times slower than `metaflac`. How to speed up `ffprobe`?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, tags, multi-threaded, ffprobe

On a small FLAC folder of 1593 files, `ffprobe` takes over 12 times longer to run than `metaflac`. How to speed up the single-threaded performance of `ffprobe`?

I tried to tell `ffprobe` to do the same and print only the `VORBIS_COMMENT` or `TAG` field by running `ffprobe -show_entries format_tags ..`, but this unfortunately doesn't improve the performance.

This script searches for possible URLs:

1.`ffprobe`:

```
$ time find . -type f -iname "*.flac" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' FILENAME; do
    INFOS=$(ffprobe -hide_banner "$FILENAME" 2>&1)
    URL=$("$INFOS"|& grep -i 'http\|www')
    if [ "$URL" != "" ]; then
        echo -e "$FILENAME\t$URL"
    fi
done | column -t -s $'\t'
```

2.`metaflac`:

(only this line is different:)

```
...
    INFOS=$(metaflac --list --block-type=VORBIS_COMMENT "$FILENAME" 2>&1)
...
```

Benchmarks:

The CPU is a Ryzen 5600X and the files are located on an external 850 EVO 1TB SSD.

Single-threaded benchmarks:

|  | $ time find .. |
| --- | --- |
| `metaflac` | `real 0m2,579s` |
| `mediainfo` | `real 0m14,222s` |
| `ffprobe` | `real 0m32,379s` |
| `exiftool` | `real 1m21,881s` |

**Edit**
To speed things up I modified my code to run in parallel:

```
getURLs() {
    FILENAME=$1
    URL=$(mediainfo "$FILENAME" 2>&1 | grep -i 'http\|www')
    if [ "$URL" != "" ]; then
        echo -e "$FILENAME\t$URL"
    fi
}

find . -type f -iname "*.flac" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' FILENAME; do
    getURLs "$FILENAME" &
done | column -t -s $'\t'

wait
```

This parallelized script version utilizes my 5600X CPU fully and the performance seems to be CPU-bound:

Multi-threaded benchmarks:

|  | $ time find .. |
| --- | --- |
| `metaflac` | `real 0m0,695s` |
| `mediainfo` | `real 0m2,109s` |
| `ffprobe` | `real 0m4,844s` |

I'm asking for a single-threaded speed improvement of `ffprobe`, so I won't mark this as a solution, though it's a nice speed improvement indeed.